# Ember transition not triggering on refresh

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I'm having a issue where transitioning is not occurring on a page reload/refresh. When I start the application and click on the links, everything works perfectly, but when I reload the route - I get an empty page (blank). This is happening for me on the **MovieIndexRoute** below.

```
// Router
MediaUi.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('movies', { path: '/'}, function() {
    this.resource('movie', { path: 'movie/:id' }, function() {
      this.route('edit', { path: '/edit' });
    });
  });
});

// Movies Route
MediaUi.MoviesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var media;

    media = MediaUi.Media.find();

    return media;
  }
});

// Movie Route
MediaUi.MovieRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    return { id: model.get('_id') };
  }
});

// Movie Index Route
MediaUi.MovieIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('movie');
  }
});
```

You can also access the repo here: https://github.com/alvincrespo/media-ui/tree/nested-resources on the nested-resources branch.

I've also added the following screenshot, showing the page and console.[image: Page Refresh Screenshot]

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!